# Apache Ivy and configurations

Tags: ivy, dependency-management

I'm using Ivy to manage my dependencies, with some problems on provided jars

This is my ivy.xml file

```xml
<configurations>
    <conf name="local" visibility="private" />
    <conf name="compile" description="used for building" />
    <conf name="test" extends="compile" description="used for testing" />
    <conf name="runtime" description="used for running" />
    <conf name="master" description="used for publishing" />
    <conf name="default" extends="master, runtime" />
</configurations>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="xalan" name="xalan" rev="2.7.1"/>
    <dependency org="org.w3c.css" name="sac" rev="1.3"/>
    <dependency org="com.lowagie" name="itext" rev="2.0.8">
            <exclude org="bouncycastle"/>
    </dependency>
<!--Provided-->
<dependency org="javax.ejb" name="ejb-api" rev="3.0" conf="compile"/>
<dependency org="javax.jms" name="jms-api" rev="1.1-rev-1" conf="compile"/>
</dependencies>
```

Ejb and jms are provided by the container

Affer execute  I obtain

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      compile     |   8   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   6   |   0   |
|      default     |   6   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   6   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So Ivy is getting fine the dependencies but when I execute this

```xml
<ivy:cachepath pathid="normal.classpath" />
<pathconvert property="expanded.normal.classpath" refid="normal.classpath"/>
<echo message="${expanded.normal.classpath}" file="normal.classpath.txt"/>

<ivy:cachepath conf="compile" pathid="compile.classpath" />
<pathconvert property="expanded.compile.classpath" refid="compile.classpath"/>
<echo message="${expanded.compile.classpath}" file="compile.classpath.txt"/>
```

Both classpath are the same.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `ivy:cachepath` has no conf defined, to it resolve all configurations, so every module is included.

The second `ivy:cachepath` is requesting only the conf compile. So the dependencies which are declared as `conf="compile"` (synonymous of `conf="compile->compile"`) are obviously included. And the dependencies without any `conf` attribute are also included, because the default conf is `*->*`.

More documentation about configurations on dependencies:

- "Configurations mapping" in http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html
- `defaultconf` attribute in http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependencies.html

Comment: Thanks. After set up the other dependencies with "runtime" is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reducing the number of configurations and ensure each dependency has an explicit mapping.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
  <configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="used for building"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="used for running" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="test"    description="used for testing" extends="runtime"/>
  </configurations>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- compile dependencies -->
    <dependency org="javax.ejb" name="ejb-api" rev="3.0" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.jms" name="jms-api" rev="1.1-rev-1" conf="compile->default"/>

    <!-- runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency org="xalan" name="xalan" rev="2.7.1" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.w3c.css" name="sac" rev="1.3" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.lowagie" name="itext" rev="2.0.8" conf="runtime->default">
      <exclude org="bouncycastle"/>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

This will produce the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      compile     |   2   |   2   |   2   |   0   ||   2   |   2   |
|      runtime     |   7   |   7   |   7   |   0   ||   7   |   7   |
|       test       |   7   |   7   |   7   |   0   ||   7   |   7   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Demonstrating how there are only 2 jars on you compile configuration (as expected) and how the test configuration is identical to runtime (expected because one extends the other).
I find it rare to need more than these 3 distinct classpaths in an ANT build build.

## Additional

I noticed in your report nothing was downloaded. The [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) task is useful to run periodically and make sure your build is fresh.

The [report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) ivy is also very useful to understand the transitive dependencies properly.

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:report todir='build/ivy' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```